# Difficulty understanding function for simple calculator (Stroustrop Programming Principles book)

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple calculator following the book "Bjarne Stroustrups' Programming Principles and Practice using C++". I feel like I'm finally starting to get a good grasp on basic C++, however, I have found some difficulty in this particular question. In chapter 7.7, he describes writing a function to purge input from a 'token buffer' so that if you are writing multiple equations on a single line of input (i.e. "1+2= 3+2=" on one line) it would skip any equations that threw errors (i.e. "&+%= 3+2=" it would skip the first equation).

The particular function I am confused about is:

```
void tokenstream::purge(char c) {

if (isFull && c == buffer.kind) { // purges 'c' from buffer
    isFull = false;
    return;
} 
isFull = false; // purges buffer regardless

char ch = 0;
while (cin >> ch) if (ch == c) return;
}
```

In the book this function is described as - "This code first looks at the buffer. If there is a 'c' there, we are finished after discarding that 'c'; otherwise, we need to read characters from cin until we find a 'c'."

How does 'cin' read input as described? I thought 'cin' required user input, so I do not see how it is useful in this case. I thought that you would rather 'search' the existing input (i.e. the equation the user entered), rather then asking for more input.

I am sorry if this question is confusing, I have included my code below, the header is accessed from http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h (but I don't believe it is that relevant regardless).

Thanks,

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "../../ConsoleColor.h"

/*----------------------constants------------------------*/
const char number = '#'; // represents the 'number' member of the token class
const string eval_sign = "= "; // represents the 'answer' command
const string prompt = "> "; // represents the 'answer' command

/*-------------------token handling----------------------*/
class token {
public:
    char kind;
    double value;
    token(char ch) : kind(ch), value(0) {} // initialise default character token
    token(char ch, double val) : kind(ch), value(val) {} // initialise default number token
};

class tokenstream {
public:
    tokenstream() :isFull(false), buffer(0) {} // initialise default tokenstream (not full, no buffer)
    token get(); // retrieves token from tokenstream
    void putback(token t); // puts <cin> input into tokenstream (1 character max)
    void purge(char ch); // discards characters up to and including 'ch'
private:
    bool isFull;
    token buffer;
};

token tokenstream::get() {
    if (isFull) { // retrieves token if buffer is full
        isFull = false;
        return buffer;
    }

    char input; // retrieves token from input
    cin >> input;

    switch (input) {
        case'+': case'-': case'/': case'*': case'(': case')': case'%': // operators
        case'q': case'=': // q = quit, '=' = print
        {
            return token(input); // returns 'character' token (i.e. operators, quit, and print commands)
        }
        case'0': case'1': case'2': case'3': case'4': case'5': // numbers (and decimal point)
        case'6': case'7': case'8': case'9': case'.':
        {
            double continued_input;
            cin.putback(input); // put the first number back into the input stream
            cin >> continued_input; // finish the number (i.e. multiple digits, or decimal point)
            return token(number, continued_input); // returns 'number' token
        }
    }

}

void tokenstream::putback(token t) {
    if (isFull) error("putback() into full tokenstream buffer");
    else {
        isFull = true;
        buffer = t;
    }
}

void tokenstream::purge(char c) { // I NEED EXPLANATION OF THIS
    if (isFull && c == buffer.kind) { // purges 'c' from buffer
        isFull = false;
        return;
    }
    isFull = false; // purges buffer regardless

    char ch = 0;
    while (cin >> ch) if (ch == c) return;
}

/*--------------------initialisation--------------------*/
tokenstream tstream;
double expression();

/*----------------------functions-----------------------*/
double primary() {
    token t = tstream.get(); // gets first token
    switch (t.kind) {
        case number: {
            return t.value;
        }
        case '(': {
            double calc = expression();
            token t = tstream.get();
            if (t.kind != ')') error("expected ')'");
            return calc;
        }
        case '+': { // handles + prefix
            t = tstream.get();
            return t.value;
        }
        case '-': { // handles - prefix
            t = tstream.get();
            return -t.value;
        }
        default: error("expected primary()");
    }
}

double term() {
    double l_calc = primary(); // evaluates first token (if primary, returns value)
    token t = tstream.get(); // gets second token

    while (true) {
    switch (t.kind) { // evaluates for * and /
        case '*': {
            double calc = primary();
            calc = (l_calc * calc);
            return calc;
        }
        case '/': {
            double calc = primary();
            if (calc == 0) error("cannot divide by zero");
            calc = (l_calc / calc);
            return calc;
        }
        default:
            tstream.putback(t);
            return l_calc;
    }
    }
}

double expression() {
    double l_calc = term(); // evaluates first token (if term, returns value)
    token t = tstream.get(); // gets second token

    while (true) {
        switch (t.kind) { // evaluates for + and -
        case '+': {
            double calc = term();
            calc = (l_calc + calc);
            return calc;
        }
        case '-': {
            double calc = primary();
            calc = (l_calc - calc);
            return calc;
        }
        default:
            tstream.putback(t);
            return l_calc;
        }
    }
}

void skip_equation() {
    tstream.purge('='); // searches for '=' and destroys input
}

void calculate() {
    while (cin) {
        try {
            cout << prompt;
            token t = tstream.get(); // checks to see if 'next token' is a 'q' or '='
            if (t.kind == '=') t = tstream.get(); // eats '=' to allow for multiple calculations on same line
            else if (t.kind == 'q') break;
            else tstream.putback(t); cout << eval_sign << expression() << endl; // if 'next token' isn't 'q' or '=' puts back token and starts calculation
        }
        catch (exception& e) {
            cerr << e.what() << endl; // writes error message
            skip_equation(); // recovers from error
        }
    }
}

int main() {
try {
/*-----------------------main---------------------------*/

    cout << red << "Welcome to SimpleCalculator" << endl;
    cout << "Enter an equation! (supports +, -, /, and *)" << endl;
    cout << "Type '=' to see your answer, or type 'q' to quit!" << white << endl;

    calculate();

/*------------------------------------------------------*/
}
catch (exception &e) {
    cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "Error: unknown" << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought 'cin' required user input, so I do not see how it is useful in this case.

The purpose of this function is to clear out user input until a certain character is found, for example to discard the rest of an input line after a parse error if the user entered a malformed formula. In this case you would pass `'\n'` as the character to search for. You want to discard input so that the user can enter something new, no matter where the input currently is.

The thing here is that there are multiple buffers at multiple levels. There is the buffer inside `tokenstream` that the function looks at first. But there is also a buffer inside `cin`, and there's probably another buffer somewhere inside the lower-level API or even the operating system.

When the user enters data in the command line, first the operating system buffers it. When you access the `tokenstream`, the stream will check its own buffer, see that it's empty, and ask `cin` for more data. `cin` will check its own buffer, see that it's empty, and ask the OS for more data. At this point, a block of data will be moved from the OS to `cin`, and `cin` then passes the data (or some of it) on to the `tokenstream`.

Because of these multiple buffers, `purge` must do several things. First, it has to discard the `tokenstream`'s buffer. If this buffer already contained the searched-for character, `purge` is done, but if not, it has to go to `cin` to read and discard more input which may have been buffered there, until the character in question is found.

Answer (score 0):

It doensn't look for the char literal `c`, but whichever char is passed as an argument. In the example it is only called with the literal '='.